# Linux source path issue with nvidia graphic driver installation

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I'm trying to install nvidia driver on Ubuntu Linux 20.

**The issue** - I'm getting the following error during installation.

> If you are using a Linux 2.6 kernel, please make sure
> you have configured kernel sources matching your kernel
> installed on your system. If you specified a separate
> output directory using either the "KBUILD_OUTPUT" or
> the "O" KBUILD parameter, make sure to specify this
> directory with the SYSOUT environment variable or with
> the equivalent nvidia-installer command line option.
>
> Depending on where and how the kernel sources (or the
> kernel headers) were installed, you may need to specify
> their location with the SYSSRC environment variable or
> the equivalent nvidia-installer command line option.

**What I tried so far**

1. tried to pass the `--kernel-source-path` option

   ```
   sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.17.run --kernel-source-path /lib/modules/5.11.0-34-generic/build
   ```
2. tried setting `SYSSRC` environment variable

   ```
   export SYSSRC /lib/modules/5.11.0-34-generic/build
   sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.17.run
   ```

As far I understand it tries to compile the driver against the current running kernel version `5.11.0-34-generic` but for some reason it can't find the `kernel.h` file or the whole source directory, maybe I mis-configure something. I also tried cloning the Linux kernel repository, checked out the matching branch and set the `--kernel-source-path` to this directory but it didn't work.

Here is the [readme file](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/319.17/README/index.html).

Comment: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/473713-Nvidia-driver-fails-to-install-under-kernel-3-3 Please see if the 3rd answer solves your issue. The distro does not matter in this case. Make sure you have the packages installed, or at least their equivalents for ubuntu,as suggested in the answer

Comment: @Alex Looks promising solution, But `make cloneconfig` and `make prepare` didn't work. I found *unistd.h* though in /urs/include/ folder, I tried copying it to /lib/modules/5.11.0-34-generic/linux but it didn't work.